# The return type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget)' isn't a 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I've upgraded packages on my flutter project, which has now caused the following issue:

```
The return type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget)' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.
```

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
        statusBarColor: Colors.black, statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark));
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _willPopCallback(context),
      child: BaseView<HomeViewModel>(
        onModelReady: (model) => model.setupHome(),
        builder: (context, model, child) => BotToastInit (
          child: MaterialApp(
            navigatorObservers: [BotToastNavigatorObserver()],
            home: Scaffold(
              body: HomeBodyView(context),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The culprit is the BotToastInit, which comes from this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/bot_toast). If I remove this it works, but I need this. Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BoatTostInit returns a Function that is the actual builder function!

So above your code place

```
final botToastBuilder = BotToastInit();  -
```

Then replace BotToastInit with botToastBuilder (and add the context parameter).

```
botToastBuilder(context, MaterialApp...)
```

Comment: Oh okay I see thank you!  builder: (context, model, child) => botToastBuilder (
          context,
          MaterialApp(
            navigatorObservers: [BotToastNavigatorObserver()],
            home: Scaffold(
              body: HomeBodyView(context),
            ),
          ),
        ),